# How do I make an image grid with logos? Photoshop, Illustrator or Indesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, logo, grids

I'm looking for a way to make automated image grids to be filled with logos.
Like this one:

[image: Logo List]

I work on a firm which every month makes an event and invites hundreds of companies to participate. There are also participants that receive an image (like the one on the top) with all the logos. Is there any way to make this process quicker instead of placing logos one by one?

Thanks in advance. Hope anybody can share a solution with me.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any tutorials? What problems have you run into? Showing more effort will likely get you better answers. Welcome to GraphicDesign!

Comment: Yeah. I'm still getting to know GraphicDesign Stack Exchange and the best ways I could express my doubts. Thanks for the suggestion.

Regarding the questions, I've tried everything from Illustrator to Photoshop but after the answer by Voxwoman I'm now using InDesign (by making a grid and then dragging all the logo images into those squares. It's almost automatic). It it seems the fastest way to achieve something like the image on the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to place a grid of images automatically in InDesign.

1. Select all of the images you want to place on the page in the folder where they are located.
2. Drag all the images onto the InDesign page. let go of the mouse button. Your cursor will now be a thumbnail of the "top" image with a number in parenthesis indicating how many images are in the stack.
3. Hold **Shift+Ctrl (or Cmd)** The cursor will change to an empty grid. (on Windows- not sure how this works on a Mac) Use the arrow keys to increase/decrease the number of rows/columns in the grid.
4. Once you have the number you want, Drag the bounding box for the grid. When you release the mouse, the images will be arranged in the grid.

The image toolbar also has buttons that will adjust how the images are cropped.

Comment: Thanks... I'm using this method with some changes. I draw the grid first and then I drag the logos. Different path, same end result. 
Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.